# Unable to redirect on controller from @Html.ActionLink in mvc .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to login to the website from different pages and return to that URL. But I am not able to call my controller.

Suppose:
I am trying to call the controller from this URL:
http://localhost:50208/VendorStore/40/Products/Categories

and declare controller at
http://localhost:50208/VendorStore/Account/ExternalLoginCallback

but when click on the button it redirects at http://localhost:50208/VendorStore/40/Account/ExternalLoginCallback

Login button code:

```
 `@Html.ActionLink("Login", "ExternalLoginCallback","Account", new { returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, null) `
```

Controller code:

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I understood you have an area VendorStore declared in the URL, if yes, then add it to ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "ExternalLoginCallback","Account", new { area = "VendorStore", returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, null)
```

Comment: Thank you for response, Yes I have an area VendorStore. I tried as you suggested, and got same result(http://localhost:50208/VendorStore/40/Account/ExternalLoginCallback).

How I can remove 40 from url

Comment: @PawanKumar check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { Area = "AreaName" }, null)
```

**Note:** 4th parameter is to pass route Values, if you pass an empty parameter it will consider root structure and if you pass appropriate value it use it as area.

Also do not forget to use `null` or `new{}` as the 5th parameter because passing `null` or `new {}` while creating action link will not overload method for (text,action,controller,route data) or its `(text,action,controller,route data,html attribute)` so use the proper method

In your project:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { Area = "VendorStore", returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery  }, null)
```

Comment: I have tried with "@Html.ActionLink("Login", "ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { area = "VendorStore", returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery }, htmlAttributes: new { })" and got same.